# neo4j-graphql-js custom return type for @cypher query

Tags: neo4j, graphql, neo4j-graphql-js

I'm trying to extend the graphql schema autogenerated with `neo4j-graphql-js`

this is my graphql schema

**typeDefs**

```
type Person {
   _id: Long!
   addresslocation: Point!
   confirmedtime: DateTime!
   healthstatus: String!
   id: String!
   name: String!
   performs_visit: [Visit] @relation(name: "PERFORMS_VISIT", direction: OUT)
   visits: [Place] @relation(name: "VISITS", direction: OUT)
   VISITS_rel: [VISITS]
}

type Place {
   _id: Long!
   homelocation: Point!
   id: String!
   name: String!
   type: String!
   part_of: [Region] @relation(name: "PART_OF", direction: OUT)
   visits: [Visit] @relation(name: "LOCATED_AT", direction: IN)
   persons: [Person] @relation(name: "VISITS", direction: IN)
}

type Visit {
   _id: Long!
   duration: String!
   endtime: DateTime!
   id: String!
   starttime: DateTime!
   located_at: [Place] @relation(name: "LOCATED_AT", direction: OUT)
   persons: [Person] @relation(name: "PERFORMS_VISIT", direction: IN)
}

type Region {
   _id: Long!
   name: String!
   places: [Place] @relation(name: "PART_OF", direction: IN)
}

type Country {
   _id: Long!
   name: String!
}

type Continent {
   _id: Long!
   name: String!
}



type VISITS @relation(name: "VISITS") {
  from: Person!
  to: Place!
  duration: String!
  endtime: DateTime!
  id: String!
  starttime: DateTime!
}
```

Now i extends **Person** to perform a custom query, in order to do that i'm using the `@cypher` directive

**typeDefs2**

```
type Person {
        potentialSick: [Person] @cypher(statement: """
            MATCH (p:this)--(v1:Visit)--(pl:Place)--(v2:Visit)--(p2:Person {healthstatus:"Healthy"})
            return *
        """)
  }
```

I create the schema by merging the two typeDefs and it works as expected

```
export const schema = makeAugmentedSchema({
    typeDefs: mergeTypeDefs([typeDefs, typeDefs2]),
    config: {
        debug: true,
    },
});
```

**QUESTION**

It is possible to return a custom type (mapped in graphql) from my custom query `potentialSick` ?

My goal is to return a type similar to this

```
type PotentialSick {
    id: ID
    name: String
    overlapPlaces: [Place] 
}
```

where overlap places is the `pl` in my neo4j query

```
MATCH (p:this)--(v1:Visit)--(pl:Place)--(v2:Visit)--(p2:Person {healthstatus:"Healthy"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that `neo4j-graphql-js` is a query builder, so i can obtain my data by using graphql just using the main schema. And my query will be:

```
{
  Person(filter: { healthstatus: "Sick" }) {
    id
    visits {
      _id
      persons(filter: { healthstatus: "Healthy" }) {
        _id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with this principle in mind for more complex queries that needs `@cyper` i can extend the base schema of each type and rely on graphql features

as an example

```
type Person {
        potentialSick: [Place] @cypher(statement: """
            MATCH path =(this)-[:VISITS]->(place:Place)<-[:VISITS]-(p2:Person {healthstatus:"Healthy"})
            return place
        """)
```

potentialSick return `places` and then to obtain the person that visit that place i can just use graphql

```
{
  Person(filter: { healthstatus: "Sick" }) {
    id
    potentialSick {
      persons (filter: { healthstatus: "Healthy" }){
        _id
      }
    }
  }
}
```